# EhCache replication over JMS using MQSeries

Tags: jms, replication, ehcache, ibm-mq

Can anyone advise whether this is possible and if so how the ehcache.xml should be configured and the custom connection factory be coded? I have it working for ActiveMQ which is well documented but can find no mention of WMQ.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

WebSphereMQ is also JMS compliant as ActiveMQ, so your configuration might look like this (this configuration uses providerURL pointing to localhost, customize it to your needs):

```
<cache name="sampleCacheNorep"
  maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"
  eternal="false"
  timeToIdleSeconds="1000"
  timeToLiveSeconds="1000"
  overflowToDisk="false">
  <cacheEventListenerFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheReplicatorFactory"
   properties="replicateAsynchronously=false, replicatePuts=false,
   replicateUpdates=false, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false,
   replicateRemovals=false, loaderArgument=sampleCacheNorep"
   propertySeparator=","/>
<cacheLoaderFactory 
  class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheLoaderFactory"
  properties="initialContextFactoryName=netcom.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory,
       providerURL=localhost:1414/SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN,
       replicationTopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=topicConnectionFactory,
       getQueueConnectionFactoryBindingName=queueConnectionFactory,
       replicationTopicBindingName=ehcache,
       getQueueBindingName=ehcacheGetQueue,
       timeoutMillis=10000"/>
</cache>
```